# Makemigrations not detecting changes on elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Django 1.11 app on Elastic Beanstalk.

I have a model `Profile` as part of an app `grams` and I added a field `email_verified` to the model. When I ran makemigrations locally, it picks up the change right away. When I push to elastic beanstalk using `eb deploy` it runs makemigrations but discovers no changes, then runs migrate and discovers no changes.

This server has been running for months and has had multiple successful migrations.

Here is the error message after trying to log in after a deployment.

```
    Internal Server Error: /signin/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 385, in __get__
        rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
    AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_profile_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column grams_profile.email_verified does not exist
LINE 1: ...ofile"."user_id", "grams_profile"."phone_number", "grams_pro...
```

Here is the deployment script:

```
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true

  02_makemigrationsgrams:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations grams --noinput"
    leader_only: true

  03_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true

  04_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true

  05_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
    option_name: /static/
    value: static/

packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []

files:
  "/opt/python/log/django.log" :
    mode: "000666"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      # Django Log File

  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Please let me know of any other information I could provide to help.

Comment: You should *not* be running makemigrations on your server. Migrations are part of your code base. Make them locally, commit them to version control, deploy them and then run them.

Comment: We have been making migrations locally and not committing them to version control because they cause conflicts when merging. I will try adding them to the staging branch.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Roseman is correct!

I removed */migrations/* from my .ebignore file but left it in my .gitignore file to ensure they don't end up in git.

All work perfect now.